# Rails reorder isn't working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Feedback model which two other models (Comment and Review) inherit from.

I have a default scope in the feedback model which orders by id `asc`

I've added a scope to the feedback model:

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Paginatable

  belongs_to :video

  default_scope do
    order(:id => :asc)
  end

  scope :newest, -> { reorder(:created_at => :desc) }

end
```

I have a Video model which has:

```
has_many :feedback 
has_many :latest_feedback, -> { newest }, class_name: 'Feedback'
```

The problem I'm having is that when I call

```
Video.includes(:latest_feedback).find(1)
```

It still orders feedback by `id` first and then by `created_at` which is not what I want. I want `latest_feedback` to be ordered only by `created_at`

Here's what it does:

```
Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `videos`.* FROM `videos`  WHERE `videos`.`id` = 85  ORDER BY `videos`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
Feedback Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `feedback`.* FROM `feedback`  WHERE `feedback`.`video_id` IN (1)  ORDER BY `feedback`.`id` ASC, `feedback`.`created_at` DESC
```

Here's what I need it to do:

```
Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `videos`.* FROM `videos`  WHERE `videos`.`id` = 85  ORDER BY `videos`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
Feedback Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `feedback`.* FROM `feedback`  WHERE `feedback`.`video_id` IN (1)  ORDER BY `feedback`.`created_at` DESC
```

**UPDATE**

I guess this is a known issue with rails. There is still an open pull request to fix it here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16531

It doesn't look like this will land until Rails 5.0.0 though.

Comment: What if `has_many :latest_feedback, -> { unscoped.newest }, class_name: 'Feedback'` ?

Comment: No change, unscoped.newest had no effect.

Comment: Than my advice will be avoid using `default_scope`. It seems like its appended without scope recalculation.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really an option for me. I need feedback to be ordered by id because it's an api resource where pagination depends on that scope. It wouldn't be practical for me to try and manually apply that default scope everywhere throughout my code base.

Comment: You can try `Video.joins(:latest_feedback).reorder('feedback.created_at desc').find(1)`

Comment: That seems to work but isn't what I would consider an ideal solution

Comment: What about `Video.joins(:latest_feedback).find(1)` ? Does it remove default scope?

Comment: Yes, no default scope.

Comment: Thats why its recomended not to use default_scope) Its behavior is weird

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Video.joins(:latest_feedback).find(1)`. It seems like Rails appends default scope without scope recalculation on `includes`

Comment: But it doesn't include the `newest` scope either

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Video.includes(:latest_feedback).order('feedbacks.id desc').find(1)`

Comment: There would be no point in having `has_many :latest_feedback, -> { newest }, class_name: 'Feedback'` in my model if this is how it has to be done. But I'm not convinced that this is the way it has to happen.